# lower triangle inequality for complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

prove $|z_1 + z_2| \geq ||z_1| - |z_2||$ I have proved the original triangle inequality.

Using the original I have ended up with $$|z_1+z_2| \geq |z_1| - |z_2|$$
and $$|z_1+z_2| \geq -(|z_1|-|z_2|)$$

but does this mean the result holds? I mean, if we had say $|x| \geq 10$, then that means that $x \geq 10$ or $x \leq -10$, so i don't see how to conmclude the result from here

Comment: While your last sentence is true, it isn't really relevant in this situation. Rather, what you can say is that if $|x| \geq |a|$, then $|x| \geq a$ and $|x| \geq -a$ (here $a \in \mathbb{R}$); what you are doing is going in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $x \geq a$ and $x \geq b$, then $x \geq \max\{a, b\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$|z_1| \leq |z_1 - z_2| + |z_2| \Rightarrow |z_1| - |z_2| \leq |z_1 + z_2|.$

$|z_2| \leq |z_2 - z_1| + |z_1| \Rightarrow |z_1| - |z_2|  \geq -|z_1 + z_2|.$

Hence, $-|z_1 + z_2| \leq |z_1| - |z_2| \leq |z_1 + z_2| \Rightarrow ||z_1|-|z_2|| \leq |z_1 + z_2|.$